# Iterate calculations in a function Spark-Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have designed a function that does a series of equal calculations for different columns. The function is:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

def calculoVariables(table: DataFrame, variable: String): DataFrame = {
            
        val D_1 = "pl_"
        val D = "pos_" 
        val fxRate = "fxtoeur"
        val Acumulado = variable + "_ac"
        val varPositionD = D + variable
        val AcumuladoD_1 = D_1 + variable + "_ac"
        val LocalAvgAc= variable + "_localavg_ac"
        val LocalAvgAcD_1 = D_1 + variable + "_localavg_ac"
        
table.withColumn(Acumulado, when( ($"Tipo" === "Normal"), col(varPositionD))
                           .when( ($"Tipo" === "Nueva"),  col(varPositionD))
                           .when( ($"Tipo" === "Cancelada"), 0.0)
                           .otherwise( col(AcumuladoD_1)))
     .withColumn(LocalAvgAc, when( ($"Tipo" === "Normal"), (col(LocalAvgAcD_1) + ((col(Acumulado) - col(AcumuladoD_1)) * col(fxRate))))
                            .when( ($"Tipo" === "Cancelada"), 0.0)
                            .otherwise( (col(LocalAvgAcD_1) + ((col(Acumulado) - col(AcumuladoD_1)) * col(fxRate)  ))))                                  
      }
```

I want you to do this for a single DataFrame but for the different fields for example in a List ("sales", "prize", "telephone") for example.

This function indicating a value works perfectly, but I can't get it to do it iteratively.

Thank you so much!

Comment: can you add input data & expected output data ?

Comment: In the end I did it with @tailrec and you can see the solution in the following link in case it helps you in the future: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944511/spark-scala-not-work-with-tailrec-withcolumn)