# Spark/Scala not work with @tailrec + withColumn

Tags: scala, apache-spark

After giving it a few laps I managed to get here:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def getRangeData(variable: List[String], table: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    @tailrec
    def unionRangeData(variable: List[String], table: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
        
        if (variable.isEmpty) {
          table
        }
        else {
        
        val D_1 = "pl_"
        val D = "pos_" 
        val fxRate = "fxtoeur"
        val Acumulado = variable.head + "_ac"
        val varPositionD = D + variable.head
        val AcumuladoD_1 = D_1 + variable.head + "_ac"
        table.withColumn(Acumulado, when( ($"Tipo" === "Normal"), col(varPositionD))
                                   .when( ($"Tipo" === "Nueva"),  col(varPositionD))
                                   .when( ($"Tipo" === "Cancelada"), 0.0)
                                   .otherwise( col(AcumuladoD_1)))
        }
    }
    unionRangeData(variable.tail, table)
  }
```

The function is well defined and does not give errors. The problem comes from trying to execute it, it does not modify the dataframe. That is, it returns the same input dataframe ... Any idea what might be happening?

Answer (score 0):

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def getRangeData(variable: List[String], table: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
    @tailrec
    def unionRangeData(variable: List[String], table: DataFrame): DataFrame = {
        
        if (variable.isEmpty) {
          table
        }
        else {
        
        val D_1 = "pl_"
        val D = "pos_" 
        val fxRate = "fxtoeur"
        val Acumulado = variable.head + "_ac"
        val varPositionD = D + variable.head
        val AcumuladoD_1 = D_1 + variable.head + "_ac"
         unionRangeData(variable.tail, table.withColumn(Acumulado, when( ($"Tipo" === "Normal"), col(varPositionD))
                                   .when( ($"Tipo" === "Nueva"),  col(varPositionD))
                                   .when( ($"Tipo" === "Cancelada"), 0.0)
                                   .otherwise( col(AcumuladoD_1))))
        }
    }
    unionRangeData(variable.tail, table)
  }
```

This solves the error that it does not do the withColumn but ignores the first term of the list ...

Any solution?

SOLVED: All thanks to Leo C

In the last unionRangeData (variable.tail, table) it has to be unionRangeData (variable, table)

Thank you

Comment: Shouldn't the `unionRangeData(variable.tail, table)` call be `unionRangeData(variable, table)` if you want to include the first element?

Comment: The whole reason. I had not noticed to modify the second unionRangeData. Now I include the solution in case it helps someone.

Thanks a lot!